# performing gradient calculations with LINEST 5000 times without manually inputting code

Tags: vba, excel, loops, gradient

I'm trying to perform gradient calculations on sets of force-distance curve data. I seem to have the calculation code for 100 sets of data (x,y) although continuing this manually to 5000 would take a lot of time. I was wondering if there was a function in which I could perform in order to pursue the calculations to 5000 sets of x,y data. is it a loop function? sorry for this but I'm a bio-physicist and new to coding.

Below is some examples of my code:

```
  Sub S_Grad_Extraction()
'
' S_Grad_Extraction Macro
'

'
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=LINEST(Sheet1!R[10]C:R[14]C,Sheet1!R[10]C[1]:R[14]C[1])"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=LINEST(Sheet1!R[9]C[2]:R[13]C[2],Sheet1!R[9]C[3]:R[13]C[3])"
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=LINEST(Sheet1!R[8]C[4]:R[12]C[4],Sheet1!R[8]C[5]:R[12]C[5])"
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=LINEST(Sheet1!R[7]C[6]:R[11]C[6],Sheet1!R[7]C[7]:R[11]C[7])"
    Range("A5").Select
```

Edit: added to code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you are trying to acheive but a for loop used with `Range.Offset`  may do the job.

```
For i = 0 To 5000 - 1
    Dim x As String, y As String
    x = Sheet1.Range("A11:A15").Offset(0, i * 2).Address(False, False, xlA1, True)
    y = Sheet1.Range("B11:B15").Offset(0, i * 2).Address(False, False, xlA1, True)

    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Formula = "=LINEST(" + x + "," + y + ")"
Next i
```

Regards

Comment: many thanks Seb, this seems to be working very well with one small exception. A and B are one set of data, C and D are the next. the VB code seems to place the next gradient calculation as B and C, then C and D. Is there a small change in the original code I need to make. many thanks again and hope to here from you soon.

Comment: Are you sure you used the last version of code because i fixed it in a previous edit.  Make sure the offset is `Sheet1.Range("A11:A15").Offset(0, i * 2)`

Comment: Fantastic stuff Seb, the amended code is brilliant! Cant thank you enough. I really need to learn VB and get manipulating the data myself. your help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks. If theres any thinkg i can do to rate you higher (as I'm new to this too) please let me know.

Comment: By the way thank you, I just discovered the `linest` function